# Matrix Multiplier %*% error

Tags: r, matrix

I am multiplying matrices created here...

```
CreateMatrix <- function(frame,env){

  M = matrix(c(frame$EE[env],0,0,frame$Fe[env],
               frame$EL[env],frame$LL[env],0,0,
               0,frame$LP[env],frame$PP[env],0,
               0,0,frame$PA[env],frame$AA[env]), 
             nrow=4,byrow=T)
  return(M)
}

Models = list()
   for (i in seq(0,16)){
  newModel <- CreateMatrix(Total,i)
  Models[[i+1]] <- newModel
}
```

Where "Total" is a data frame

...Recursively in the following function:

```
GrowthSeq <- function(matrix, t,P0){
 M0 = matrix(c(132,0,0,0),nrow=4)
 time = seq(0,t,1)
 G = matrix
 M = matrix(0,nrow=nrow(G),ncol=length(time))
 rownames(M)=c("Eggs","Larvae","Pupae","Adults")
 M[,1]= M0
 print(is.matrix(G))
 print(is.matrix(M))
 for (d in 2:length(time)){
   print(is.matrix(t(M[,d-1])))
   M[,d]<-G%*%t(M[,d-1])
 }
 return(M)
}

g <- GrowthSeq(Models[[1]],100,500)
```

Which results in

```
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
Error in G %*% M[, d - 1] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector argument
```

I don't understand how both of the vectors I'm multiplying are matrices but this error is still raised. Why is my attempt to multiply matrices M and G not working?

Comment: Note that your code is generally useless to us as there is no data frame called "Total" being created

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
G = matrix
```

Assigns the value of `matrix` which is an R function to the symbol `G`. It's obviously *not* a matrix. Its a function that when supplied with the correct arguments *might* make a "numeric/complex matrix/vector argument". The error is thrown by `%*%` whcih tests whether matrix multiplication makes any sense. Multiplying a numeric matrix by a function does not.

Comment: Despite changing the variable to "m" instead of "matrix", the error is still raised

Comment: That is insufficient to provide sufficient context: what "variable", what code?

Comment: In defining the function, matrix is the first variable requested. The name of "matrix" as a variable may have been ambiguous to the program as you suggested, so I changed the variable name to "m". The line now reads 'G = m' but the error is still raised

Comment: Right... so what was the value of `m`? If you execute `str(m)` what do you see?????  Furthermore, The value of `matrix` WAS NOT "ambiguous". It was a function.

Comment: m is a matrix, with structure "List of 16 $ : num 0 .... etc.... - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 4

Comment: That says `m` is a _list_. Please edit your question so it reflects what is actually being done!!!!!!!!!! First it was a function, and now it is a list. At no time has G been "numeric".

Comment: But is.matrix(m) returns TRUE?

Comment: OK. Then you have not posted the entire output. It is also possible to make a matrix composed of lists, which are not numeric.  I SAY AGAIN. POST COMPLETE CODE. AS AN EDIT TO YOUR QUESTION .... THAT'S WHAT THE 'edit' button/link is for.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you are not assigning a matrix to G, but the matrix function to G.

```
> M = matrix(c(0,1,1,0), nrow = 2)
> M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
> G = matrix
> G
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL) 
{
    if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
        data <- as.vector(data)
    .Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), 
        missing(ncol)))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001434fab0>
<environment: namespace:base>
> G%*%M
Error in G %*% M : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Because you've used `G = matrix` the G effectively becomes the matrix function. Here I can use `G` to create a matrix, just like you can with `matrix`:

```
> G(c(0,1,1,2), nrow = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    2
```

You need to **assign a matrix to G using the matrix function, rather than assign the function itself to G**. Then the multiplication works too.

```
> G = matrix(c(0,1,1,2), nrow = 2)
> G
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    2
> G%*%M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    2    1
>
```